# Gitlab pipeline error With CD/CI for AWS ec2 debian instance: This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, continuous-integration, debian, cicd

I want to create a CI/CD pipeline between gitlab and aws ec2 deployment.
My repository is nodejs/express web server project.

And I created a gitlab-ci.yaml

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - staging
  - openMr
  - production


before_script:  
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install

Build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - node
  before_script: 
    - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
    - yarn install 
  script:
    - npm run build

Test:
  stage: test
  tags:
  - node
  before_script: 
    - yarn config set cache-folder .yarn
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  script:
    - npm run test


Deploy to Production:
  stage: production
  tags:
    - node
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'   
  script:     
    - bash ./gitlab-deploy/.gitlab-deploy.prod.sh   
  environment:     
    name: production     
    url: http://ec2-url.compute.amazonaws.com:81
```

When I push a new commit pipeline failed on build step. And I get a warning as :

> This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or
> available with any of these tags assigned to them: node

I checked my runner on gitlab settings/CI/CD

[image]

[image]

After that I checkked server

```
admin@ip-111.222.222.111:~$ gitlab-runner
 statusRuntime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=18787 revision=98daeee0 version=14.7.0
FATAL: The --user is not supported for non-root users
```

Comment: The error indicates the runner won't start because you've configured a user for the runner to run as, but you can only do that with root permissions. You can try `sudo gitlab-runner` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the tag `node` from your jobs. Runner tags are used to define which runner should pick up your jobs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#use-tags-to-control-which-jobs-a-runner-can-run). As there is no runner available which supports the tag `node`, your job gets stuck.

It doesn't look like your pipeline has any special requirements so you can just remove the tag so it can be picked up by every runner.

The runner that can be seen in your screenshot supports the tag `shop_service_runner`. So another option would be to change the tag `node` to `shop_service_runner` which would lead to this runner (and every runner with the same tags) being able to pick up this job.